# Exclude some characters from a regex group

Tags: python, regex

I have a text that contains many articles concatenated into a single string. Each new article starts with `= Article 1 =` followed by `= = Article 1 Section 1 = =`, `= = Article 1 Section 2 = =` and so on. I want to split this string and create a string for each article.

For that I am using regex split

```
import re
pattern = "=[\s\w\'\(\)]+="
l = re.compile(pattern).split(test_data)
```

But this isn't giving me the desired result. The article is splitting on sections and subsections as well. I tried excluding multiple `=`s from matching but didn't find any success and not sure how to proceed on that.  I have pasted sample data(two articles) [here](https://pastebin.com/Arq2CQRA)  - `Robert Boulder` and `Kiss You ( One Direction song )`

Comment: You probably want the pattern to match the entire line, because what's happening is it's matching the first equals, whitespace `[\s]+`, and then the second equals. You can add `^$` to the pattern to match the line. You may want to split the data on newlines and trim each line, or include some optional whitespace in the regex.

Comment: I highly recommend using https://regex101.com/ to debug regex, it will highlight what's being matched and give an explanation.

Comment: Assuming your article markers start at the beginning of lines, try something like: `^= (\w| )+=`

Comment: Also, when using regex in Python, use the `r"pattern"` syntax. This uses the string contents verbatim as you intend it to.

Comment: @Jesse I was using regex101 for debugging but got confused when I read about negative look around and was trying to implement. Thanks for the r'pattern' tip

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This regex should do the job:

```
^ *= [^=]* = *$
```

See it working here:

https://regex101.com/r/l3tziI/1

Basically matching a '=' followed by a space, any numbers of characters that are NOT '=' (the `[^=]` part), then another space and another '='. Also includes optional spaces at the start and end of the line because your sample text has leading and trailing spaces on some lines.

Comment: nice catch! I've updated the answer accordingly.